# Hive sub queries

Tags: hive, hiveql

I am using a 0.X version of Hadoop. Subqueries are not allowed in this version. Can somebody help me convert the below SQL to not use subqueries.

```
select 100 * stars / total from 
(select count(rating) as stars 
from ratingshive 
where rating = 5) t1, 
(select count(1) as total 
from ratingshive) t2
```

Comment: Which database r u using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need conditional aggregation. (Also note that computed column aliases can't be used in the same query.)

```
select 100 * sum(cast(rating=5 as int)) / count(*) 
from ratingshive
```

Comment: Throws an error - `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'int)) / count(*) from ratingshive' at line 1`

Comment: this error message is for MySQL. You said Hive was being used. can you clarify?